# How to move rotated knife(RigidBody2D) diagonally?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am new to Unity and so far enjoy my journey. Right now I have accomplished my knife constant rotation within [-30;30] degrees range. However, after the user presses any key, my knife **should be moving fast in the direction it currently faces**.

How can I achieve the following behavior? I tried addForce, changing velocity, but no results... Perhaps it is even impossible to do?

[image]

Here my knife is facing the left angle and I would like to it to just **move in that direction really fast**. No fancy effects :)

[image]

Here is the initial knife position.

Here is source code:

```
public void HandleRotation()
{
    if (transform.rotation.z >= 0.3f)
    {
        right = false;
    }
    else if (transform.rotation.z <= -0.3f)
    {
        right = true;
    }

    if (right)
    {
        begin = begin + 0.05f;
    }
    else
    {
        begin = begin - 0.05f;
    }

    var tiltAroundZ = begin * tiltAngle;
    var target = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, tiltAroundZ);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, target, Time.deltaTime * smooth);

}
```

Comment: If you're trying to move it via physics engine, the first question is does it have RigidBody assigned and isKinematic is disabled?

Comment: can I have the screenshot of initial condition of your knife?

Comment: @Ankit I have updated my question

Comment: @ViktorVostrikov Sorry for my Late reply. did you used ```transform.up``` for direction?

Comment: @Ankit yes I used to transform, it worked but I run into an issue, that collisions there not triggered. In the end, I decided to change the velocity of rigidBody for movement.

Comment: @ViktorVostrikov so It's working alright now?

Comment: @Ankit yes, no issues :)

Answer (score 1):

Translate(transform.forward())? If forward is the wrong axis, you could try up or right.

There should also be a version of the Translate method that includes a space parameter, in this case you'd use Space.Self instead of Space.World, which it currently is defaulting to.

Comment: I need to move it diagonally. I have updated the question with my source code for rotation.

Comment: transform.forward will move it forward relative to its current transform. If it's facing diagonal, it will go diagonal.

Comment: Roy C, now I have another issue. Using transform instead of velocity does not take care of collisions. Here look at the difference between transform and velocity. 
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/118711/what-is-the-difference-between-transform-translate-and-rigidbody-velocity
Please, tell me how to do it with velocity.